# best way to retrieve features from server along with map position

Tags: android, kml, osmdroid, geojson

I have maptiles retrieved by my server with `osmdroid`. 
And I have a lot of features ( mainly points), that need to be retreived in certain areas of the map.

I've seen several questions about which type of file is the best for these features ( kml, geojson...), but this is not the subject of this question. I am using osmbonuspack, which provides an api for parsing those file to classic osmdroid features.

I have also found out that we can get the current location (BoundingBox) of the map in order to get the corresponding features of this area. But, what is the best way to get this data?

Downloading directly kml, geojson etc.. files or create a `REST api` on the server and implement a classic android data consumer workflow ( with network libs, loaders etc...), which might be too much

Comment: Use an `AsyncTask` to download the mappackage in the background. And also use the same `AsyncTask` to use your map points and update it on to the map as overlays using the `BoundingBox()`

Comment: So you are suggesting downloading directly those files in asyntask, and parse it? I guess if you want to save those POI, you will have to save the files on sd...

Comment: Yea, something like that!